# Call support to review an actual question

Tags: feature-request, review

Sometimes I run into questions I don't know how to handle, not even after I read the full meta. It would be nice to see how others handle those questions, and learn from that, instead of figuring out on my own. I think a new stack exchange site (for example: stack review) could be used for that, because it has been built around the same problem: concrete questions (in this case how to review an actual post?) and concrete answers.

Comment: Could you provide more details? It's not really clear what exactly you are proposing. You want a place where you can look over how other people review posts?

Comment: Nope, I want a place where I can ask how should I review an exact post which I have problem with. Or at least a documentation about how should we review posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's already a process for getting help with review: **Ask on Meta!** Make sure you go to the Meta for that particular site. Tag your question with [review](/questions/tagged/review) like you've done here. Then explain why you're having trouble with that particular review: What's confusing you? What action are you thinking is appropriate and why? What do you want explained?

Asking the entire network about a specific review item is not useful. Only someone who participates in that specific site would be able to help you because every site has differing policies on what they consider to be acceptable content, etc. The per-site Meta is the only relevant place for this.

Comment: What about writing a law for each site? Or is there already one? In modern societies we refer to the law by judging...

Comment: Meta is the best place for finding the rules and policies for a site. They are constantly being discussed all the time. If you're curious about something, just search and see if it's been brought up before. There's way too much to cover to be able to summarize *every possible thing* into a help article.

Comment: Yes, but if we never start it, then it will never be done, and ppl will ask always the same questions, because it is harder to find the answers if they are not in a single location. Law is similar, ppl discuss how it should work, they vote it in the parliament, and it is updated, so it is a living thing in every society. Why should we abandon a best practice like that? It is working for thousands of years now...

Comment: And law books are thousands of pages. We try to give users the basic information that covers most of the cases **so they'll actually read it**. Past that, separate and *searchable* questions are the best way to get further information. One page with all possible information in it is a lot less searchable.

Comment: Law books are thousands of pages, because they cover much larger topics than this. I have other opinion about what is searchable. I can easily search a single page by hitting f3 or ctrl+f and type in the related word, or simply by reading the headers. By programming we call this "clean code".

Comment: The search field in the top bar works at least as well as Ctrl+F!

Comment: A law would be inappropriate for SE sites. Their communities are constantly changing, and how they would have handled a situation a month ago may not be how they would handle it now. Discussing situations on Meta sites gives the communities the flexibility to grow in this way.

Comment: I fail to see what's the difference, a law is not carved in stone either. You can simple change it with an edit. As you said meta sites can contain out of date information about how to handle situations, because it can change month by month. That's a lot of noise... A well maintained law would contain only the current practice without any noise...